# Dynamic loading a list from a model MVC 4

Tags: c#, javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

so I'm still pretty new in ASP.net MVC design. I am facing a small problem, which might have already been answered, but don't seem to find an answer that will fit my purpose. Here is what's happening:

Say I have a model with 2 links: Category & Item, and it's a 1 to many relation. What I want to do is generate a list containing Category.Title (which I have completed, using the code following) and clicking on the each list item will generate a list of all Item.Title values of that category. The base idea of the html is:

```
<div id="cat"><!--float = left-->
    <ul>
        <li>List<li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="item"> <!--float = right -->
    <ul>
        <li>List<li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is how everything is linked up so far:

```
public ActionResult Equipment()
{

    ViewBag.Cat= getCat(1); // Will return a list of categories of ID 1
    return View();
}
```

As for the view:

```
@{ List<X.Models.Category> catX = ViewBag.Cat; }

BODY:

<div id="pl_categories">
    <ul id="pl_ec_ul">

        @foreach (X.Models.Category item in catX)
        {
            <li id="pl_ec_li">
                <div id="pl_ec_liItem">
                    @item.catTitle
                </div>
            </li>
        }

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="pl_values">

    <ul id="pl_ev_ul">
        <li id="pl_ev_li">
            <div id="pl_ev_liItem">
                ???
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have seen a bunch of examples, but they all involve dropdowns or what not. Here are a quick checklist of what I am trying to accomplish:

1. On page laod, default selected category will be the first in the list. If list is null, a simple "No Categories" is shown. Edit: if the category is empty, it will show No Items in Category.
2. On clicking an item in the category it will show the items of that    category under pl_values.

I have tried to make this is small as possible but there are a lot more factors I need to consider. However, if I can solve this, I am certain to figure out the rest. If something however is not clear, please let me know and I can try and clarify it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your item 1, you could try something like this (assuming your OK using `jQuery`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = $("#pl_ec_ul li").length;

    if(count <= 0) {
        $("#pl_categories").html("<p>No Categories</p>");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have that down :) Sorry, I mean't for the list, not the category. So if the default list has nothing, then a message will show up. Ill correct that.